# Copying an array of int8_t in C

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I have the following:

```
int8_t rtp[size];
int8_t holding[size];
```

I want to copy the value in `rtp` into `holding`.

Comment: We are not a coding service. What is your problem? What have you tried? And why did it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `memcpy()` for simply copying.

This works regardless of the type of the objects.
Insuring there are the same size is a good safeguard if the goal is to copy the entire object.

```
assert(sizeof holding == sizeof rtp);
memcpy(holding, rtp, sizeof holding);
```

Use `memmove()` if the objects may overlap - or unsure.
This is sometimes a *little* slower.  Usually this potential *slight* reduced performance is insignificant.

```
memmove(holding, rtp, sizeof holding);
```

Comment: By using `sizeof` on both, you really on them both being in automatic storage, so they can't overlap.

Comment: @ikegami True.  Overlap would need something convoluted like `union { some_type a; some_other_type b; } u;  memmove(&u.a, &u.b, sizeof u.a);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `memcpy` to copy over the whole array.

```
memcpy(holding, rtp, size * sizeof(int8_t));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size/*The size of the array*/, i++){
 holding[i] = rtp[i];
}
```